# Setup daily printing quota

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printing, network-printer, quota

Is there a way  to enforce **daily printing quota** on a PC on a **shared printer** network. The OS on the PCs are either **WinXP or Win7**.

Comment: what printer are you using ?

Comment: I am not sure about the printer. The quota has to be user-wise, so if we can enforce it on client machines...?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234270 havent u checked this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not have any printer accounting built-in.

Some printers have user accounting built in. For example, Xerox call it [Auditron](http://www.fujixerox.com.au/company/media/articles/533/). With these printers you can set user limits for both colour and mono printing.

With all other printers, the only way you can enforce quotas is by installing print management software. There are many packages available (Google "print accounting software") but not all of them support user quotas. For example, HP's WebJetAdmin and Xerox's CentreWareWeb (both free) do not. One package that does is [PaperCut](http://www.papercut.com/), which has a 40 day free trial offer.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for a commercial solution as @hdhondt said. For example you have Equitrac, Streamline NX, etc... but this is used in large enterprises and might be overkill, because you need a dedicated print server etc...

These solutions can also set limitations.